# Query improvement possible? :From link table, create groups of one field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a link table named `club_per_clubgroup`, entities `club`, `clubgroup` and `customer`.

`club_per_clubgroup`:

```
(club)    (clubgroup)
fooclub   1
barclub   2
fooclub   3
barclub   3
```

`customer` table is linked to `clubgroup`:

```
(code)   (clubgroup)
foolio   1
barman   2
wiseman  3
```

I'd need to get all clubs for customer in one field.
This is what I've done already, and it works:

```
select * from
(select distinct customer from club_customer)c
        cross apply(select
                            STUFF(  ( 
                                    select ',' + cc.club 
                                    from club_customer cc
                                    where c.customer=cc.customer
                                    order by cc.club
                                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                                ).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
                            ,1,2, '') as clubgroup
                        ) as conctbl
```

Is there any more performant alternative to gain the same?

SQL SERVER version is 2008 (R2 maybe).

Comment: Alternatives will depend on the version of SQL Server. **Always** specify, preferably with a tag (`sql-server-20xx` could easily replace `jointable` here).

Comment: I've responded in the end of the question body

Comment: Your post has so many details. Are you asking anything about your DB design, or redesign attempt? Or your question is about final select statement "optimization" only? Please remove all redundant info from the post.

Comment: The design is decided; The question regards, as you say, the final select optimazation only. I can't see which part is unneeded: I've pasted examples of the tables before and after, and my current query. I don't see what I could exclude that would make the question less readable.

Comment: Ok, I'll make the edit, don't treat it as harm attempt. You may return to the original post whenever you wish.

Comment: Don't worry, thank you for your assistance.